# How to create getter and setter

Tags: javascript, extjs

I just got assigned some project of a fired extjs developer. In the controllers he made, I found calls like

```
this.getMyButton().toggle(true);
this.getMyContainer().getLayout()...
```

So, I just added a new form to the view (one of the things my ex colleague should have had completed by christmas) and tried to call it from the controller using

```
this.getMyNewForm().loadRecord(someStore.getAt(0));
```

and Chrome tells me that `this.getMyNewForm()` is undefined. But nowhere in the code I found a definition for `getMyButton()`.

What's the matter with that? How do I define `getMyNewForm()`?

EDIT: Question answered by the docs (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs), but problem still open.

Ref is defined properly in controller:

```
refs: [{
    ref       :'MyNewForm',
    selector  :'form[id=myNewForm]'
}]
```

and MyNewForm is defined properly in view

```
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        header:false,
        frame:false,
        id:'myNewForm',
        items: [{
```

but it does not work when I call

```
 init: function() {
    this.control({
    });
    this.getMyNewForm().loadRecord(someStore.getAt(0));
 },
```

Comment: First you should study what is already there and not ,and how things have been implemented.

Comment: You're calling it too early. `init` for the controllers get called before any view is rendered.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thx! I put the call into window.afterrender and now it works. Would you mind to make an answer of that, so I can mark the question as answered? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Evan Trimboli didn't make it an answer, let me do it:

"You're calling it too early. init for the controllers get called before any view is rendered."

Answer (score 0):

You should define that method on the prototype of the constructor of your controller. The JavaScript engine moans simply because you haven't defined the getMyNewForm method; It's not magic, you cannot call a random method.

You say  that the getMyButton method is nowhere in the code. Well, that is simply impossible. It might be the case that there is a sort of inheritance hierarchy, and your controller simply inherits from a constructor which defines that method on its prototype.

Bare in mind that even if you define the getMyNewForm emthod, you should return an instance of a "class" that defines the loadRecord method; this might probably be a extjs specific "class"

Comment: I just found it in the docs, it IS magic: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs, but my problem is not yet solved. I have the ref defined now, but the method is still not available.